# Evoluent VerticalMouse 4 not working on computer restart

Tags: mac, drivers, mouse

On 2 different computer whenever I restart the mouse won't work until I unplug it and plug it back in again. I was wondering if there is a "software" way to do this something like "Refresh USB Devices" command.

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Here's some information I pulled from System Report.

```
Evoluent VerticalMouse 4:

  Product ID:   0x0191
  Vendor ID:    0x1a7c
  Version:  2.70
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: SONiX
  Location ID:  0x14123000 / 8
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

```
$ ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Evoluent VerticalMouse 4@14123000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000470, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (4 ms), retain 12>
```

Comment: https://evoluent.com/support/download/ says their drivers are out of date